# Não consigo ter acesso ao axios

Tags: javascript, async, axios, cdn

Estou usando o axios pelo cdn e aparece o erro: "Uncaught Error: URL contains XSS injection attempt"

O código Javascript do arquivo main_axios.js

```
axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/diego3g')
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.warn(error);
    });
```

O HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js'></script>
    <script src='main_axios.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: É só esse o código que você está usando? Acabei de testar e esta funcionando

Comment: não sei está acontecendo. Na pasta onde estão os 2 arquivos "C:\Users\Usuário\Documents\Programming\Javascript\assíncrono" acontece o erro, mas acabei de testar criando outros 2 arquivos com o mesmo código na área de trabalho e eles funcionaram.

Comment: Se está executando sem servidor?

Comment: não, são só esses dois arquivos

Comment: Troquei o nome da pasta "Javascript" para qualquer outra coisa que funcionou normal

Comment: Gustavo, eu estava com o mesmo problema. Use a versão 0.18 do axios, a 0.19 não está funcionando.